# Arabic fonts printed in reverse order in Apache FOP

Tags: apache-fop

I have a problem in printing the arabic fonts properly.

What happens is that they are printed in reverse order.
For e.g Take the word "The" and in arabic it should be "ehT"(think "ehT" as arabic).

And I am using Apache FOP for this but it prints in reverse order in arabic i.e. "The"

And it is compulsory to use PDF not RTF.

And using XSLT for the generation of arabic fonts on the basis of their english meaning.

Comment: I noticed a similar discussion on the FOP users mailing list. Can be accessed [here](http://old.nabble.com/FOP---Users-f353.html).

Comment: @Wivani : Thanks but we have moved to Jasper Reports since it gives support for all languages very well.